# using getdate() in filter expression of DataSet.Select() method

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I would like to know the possibility of using SQL functions (in this case getdate()) in filter expressions, like the one stated below:

```
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("MyDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("MyString", typeof(string));
            var row = dataTable.NewRow();
            row[0] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            row[1] = "XXX";

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);

            //Evaluation

            //Example 1 - IT WORKS
            //var rows = dataTable.Select("([MyString] = 'XXX') And [MyDate] > #2012/03/03#"); 

            //Example 2 - IT DOESN'T WORK
            var rows = dataTable.Select("([MyString] = 'XXX') And [MyDate] >= (GETDATE())");
```

Does anyone know if it's possible?
For some reasons I can't change the original code that just evaluate a string, and I need to fetch the current date and add more 2 days on that. something like `DATEADD(day,2,[MyDate])`

I know that one way would be changing the source code and create a literal string with date, like example 2.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate `DateTime.Now` into your filter:

```
var filter = string.Format("[MyString] = 'XXX' And [MyDate] >= #{0:yyyy-MM-dd}#", DateTime.Now);
var rows = dataTable.Select(filter);
```

If it needs to be more than two days after, then you could change `DateTime.Now`, to `DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).Date`

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this link to check if something like that is supported :
http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

I did a quick check and date functions don't seem to be supported.
How did I come across that link ? I just googled for the api you are using and came to this link first :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

clicked on the select version with one string and came to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx

I then started to read.
I am passing all this information because I think looking through what is already available on the internet and knowing what to look for and how is just as important as programming itself.

What you can do in your situation of course is to use DateTime.today to get to the current date, and create a select string that makes use of that result. Don't put DateTime.today as string in your select, that won't work either.